# Send a string list to the controller using RouteValueDictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I have a search screen which gives the results in a paged list. On changing the page I need to get the values of the Model to the GET method in the controller. While I was able to pass the model properties which are strings, I am having an issue passing the string list.

View Code :

```
<div class="divSearch">
<div class="divCriteria">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Owner)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Owner, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.County)
            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.County, Model.CountiesList, new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-share-square-o"></i>Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="divResults">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover table-advance dataTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th style="display:none">ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>County</th>                       
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @foreach (var item in Model.SearchList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ID)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.County)
                        </td>                                                 
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

@if (Model.SearchList != null)
{
var county = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in Model.County)
{
    county.Add(item);
}

@Html.PagedListPager(Model.SearchList, Page => Url.Action("Index", "FacilityFinder", new RouteValueDictionary() { { "Page", Page }, { "name", Model.Name },  { "owner", Model.Owner }, { "county", county} }),PagedListRenderOptions.PageNumbersOnly)
 }
```

Controller code :

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page=null,string name = null, List<string> county=null,string owner = null)
{
}
```

The value for name and owner are fine in the controller, but the list of county gives me System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass complex types such as lists. You might need to construct your `RouteValueDictionary` dynamically:

```
var query = new RouteValueDictionary
{ 
    { "name", Model.Name },  
    { "owner", Model.Owner }
};

for (var i = 0; i < Model.County.Count; i++)
{
    query["county[" + i + "]"] = Model.County[i];
}

@Html.PagedListPager(
    Model.SearchList, 
    Page => Url.Action("Index", "FacilityFinder", new RouteValueDictionary(query) { { "Page", Page } }),
    PagedListRenderOptions.PageNumbersOnly
)
```

so that the resulting url looks like this:

```
/FacilityFinder/Index?Page=5&name=Foo&owner=Bar&county[0]=foo1&county[1]=foo2...
```

which will make the default model binder in ASP.NET MVC happy and properly bind this to a `List<string>`.

Comment: Compilation error : A local variable named 'Page' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'Page', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else.

Comment: oops, `Page` is dynamic, I have updated my answer with an example of how to handle this.